# is there a need for php cache routine with varnish?

Tags: php, caching, varnish

I'm new to caching and whilst reading I was wondering if I should add a custom written caching routine in my php scripts (for instance for heavy select queries, or calculations).

I'm afraid these custom coded caching routines overcomplicate my scripts and add no benefit when Varnish is said to be able to do all this. So in short: is there a need for custom caching in PHP when Varnish is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish caches on a page level, while the examples you indicate are more on query/function level. 
So they are not fully comparable, and using varnish as an excuse to do no caching further down is too simplified approach.

Comment: Hi Marcel thanks for your repons. I assume I have to build in some cache system in my php than :) Thanks!